# What was the purpose of the Attic?

Tags: dollhouse

In Dollhouse, everyone fears "the attic" as a place from which no-one returns. In one episode we see the attic and people (all presumably Dolls) linked up in what looks like a neural network.

What was the purpose of the Attic?
Was it simply a place to keep troublesome Dolls (in which case why where they linked up) or where they being utilized for some specific purpose?

Comment: Have you watched the entire show yet?

Comment: @Dracs - Got both seasons on DVD, but it's been a while.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Attic was essentially a giant mainframe computer for Rossum. This was done by having everybody in the Attic being constantly subjected to a nightmare like scenarios over and over again. The repeated attempts to solve the scenario could be used by Rossum as computational power, with the nightmare like aspect increasing adrenaline (and thus improving speed).

The Attic was not limited just to Dolls Laurence Dominic was sent to the Attic after being discovered as a NSA spy and several other people are seen in the Attic who were not Dolls.

Comment: Had completely forgotten about the nightmares! Was there any specific use of the Attic ever mentioned/hinted?

Comment: @SteB Clyde Randolph founder of Rossum and first person sent to the Attic said that his repeating scenario was to determine statistical probability of where the Dollhouse technology might lead. That's as close as we get to a specific use.